# Odoo 10 - Set the value of next sequence for a IrSequence instance

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to set the value of sequence for a IrSequence model instance inside a Python method.

I would have as input values:

- the ID of the IrSequence (and getting the ID of the IrSequenceDateRange if dates are used is also possible).
- the value for the next value to be used in the sequence.

Given that ID and that value, how can I set up the next value programmatically -i.e. by python source code- for that sequence?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show me, what did you try? And please more details!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to get the next value in a sequence:

1) Given the id:

```
next_seq = seq_record.next_by_id(cr, uid, seq_id, context)
```

2) Given the code:

```
next_seq = seq_record.next_by_code(cr, uid, seq_code, context=context)
```

But if you want to change the database value directly you can try to write the record:

```
seq_rec = self.env[ir_sequence].browse(seq_id)
seq_rec.write({'number_next': your_next_sequence})
```

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks this works, just needed to check if ir_sequence or ir_sequence_date_range is being used, but it is the same for both cases.